# Resharper "Cannot analyse project output. The file does not exist"

Tags: visual-studio-2010, resharper

Been using Resharper for many years.  However, at my current place when I run all unit tests in my solution in Visual Studio 2010 using Resharper 6.1 all it's projects compile then I get the following message box appear requiring me to hit OK:

```
---------------------------
ReSharper Unit Testing
---------------------------
Cannot analyse project output.

The file does not exist.
---------------------------
OK   
---------------------------
```

The tests do not run until I press OK.  I cannot figure out why this is happening and it seems to have no adverse effects.

The problem also seems to be getting worse.  At certain points over time this problem has got worse: first I only got this message box once, now I get it fives times (I have to hit OK five times before the tests run :-))

Note: If I run an individual unit test or a class of unit tests or even all the unit tests in a particular project this does not occur.

Any ideas why this is happening? How to fix it?

Comment: To nail the problem, you may need checking what caused it. Run VS with command line:
`/ReSharper.LogFile "Z:\resharper.log" /ReSharper.LogLevel Verbose`
and then check the log file for any exceptions caught. Usually it just fails to load some assembly.

Comment: Thanks @bytebuster.  Resharper does appear to be throwing some exceptions around MetadataLoader of one of our project's MSIs: "Can't create metadata reader from MyApp.msi"

Comment: Great, now you're one step forward towards solution. You may edit your question by adding necessary details so that the others could reproduce it and provide with help.

Comment: i'm getting the same error. tried verbose logging and the files reported as missing (in the log) are actually there! I dont know how to solve this yet.